# Implent http request for two methods

Tags: go, interface

I’ve this interface which I need to implement for two calls,

```
1.   req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", "http://example.com/healthz", nil)
2. req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", "http://localhost:8082/rest/foos/9", nil)
```

But the interface is using the `req` of type `*http.Request` method, how should I do it ?

```
type HealthChecker interface {
    Name() string
    Check(req *http.Request) error
}


type ping struct{}

func (p ping) Check(req *http.Request) error {

 
}

func (ping) Name() string {
    return "check1"
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/PvpKD-_MFRS

Comment: Your similar question was closed for being unclear. Please don't just repost, clarify exactly what you want to achieve. Show how your interface is meant to be used and explain in plain words what you want to do.

Comment: @Marc  - I've complety change the question...not its much more focused

Comment: Except you still haven't explained. What do you want `Check` to do? Just issue a `Get` request? If so, why is `client.Do(req)` not  sufficient?

Comment: @Marc I want that each implematation of the check will have an url to check and return response if success or not

Comment: then use a http.Client and call `client.Do(req)` on it. The [http](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/) package docs have many examples. If that doesn't do what you need, show the code you tried and why it doesn't work.

Comment: @Marc - the `http.NewRequest("GET" ...` is working, however I want that it will be implemented as part of the `check` method...

Comment: One last time, and please just write some code: create/get an http client, then within `Check`, call `client.Do(req)`. If that's not enough, explain why, but do try something.

Comment: @Marc - I've tried something like https://play.golang.org/p/KVSRjXdj6By witout success

Comment: This isn't even valid Go, please take the [tour](https://tour.golang.org/) to learn the language basics, then read the package docs. After all this, please show code that at least compiles.

Comment: Don't use an `interface`. Define `HealthChecker` as a simple struc. Initialize each struct value with the URL you care about. Then the `Check` method can determine if the particular URL is "healthy" or not.

Comment: @colm.anseo - it will be great if you can provide simple example how to do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per my comments, don't over-complicate by using an `interface`.

A simple `struct` will suffice:

```
type HealthChecker struct {
    URL string
}

func (h HealthChecker) Check() error {
    resp, err := http.Get(h.URL)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()

    if resp.StatusCode != http.StatusOK {
        return fmt.Errorf("got http status %d instead of %d", resp.StatusCode, http.StatusOK)
    }

    return nil
}
```

To use:

```
ex := HealthChecker{"http://example.com/healthz"}

log.Println(ex.URL, ex.Check()) // http://example.com/healthz got http status 404 instead of 200


g := HealthChecker{"http://google.com/"}

log.Println(g.URL, g.Check()) // http://google.com/ <nil>
```

https://play.golang.org/p/ktb2xX7DHKI